# How to get user input data in shell (Jenkinsfile)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to take user input through Jenkinsfile but I can't use that in the shell. Here is the code:

```
def userInput =  timeout(time:60, unit:'SECONDS') {input(
     id: 'userInput', message: 'URL Required', parameters: [
     [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: '', description: 'URL', name: 'url'],
    ])
  }

node{
        echo "Env jsfsjaffwef:"+userInput) //this works
        echo "${userInput}" //but this does not
        sh '''
          python test.py ${userInput}
        '''
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure that `echo "${userInput}"` does _not_ work? What's "not working" btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful about [string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation): Variables will be replaced inside double quotes (`".."`, or the multi-line variant `"""`), but not inside single quotes (`'..'`, resp. `'''..'''`). So the `sh` step shouldn't have it replaced, the `echo` above should have it correctly.

```java
def userInput =  timeout(time:60, unit:'SECONDS') {input(
     id: 'userInput', message: 'URL Required', parameters: [
     [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: '', description: 'URL', name: 'url'],
    ])
  }

node {
        echo "Env jsfsjaffwef:"+userInput) //this works
        echo "${userInput}" // this should have also worked before
        sh """
          python test.py ${userInput}
        """
}
```

So make sure that you exactly apply the right quotes and don't just replace them compared to what people suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on Jenkins 2.62:

```
def userInput =  input(
     id: 'userInput', message: 'URL Required', parameters: [
     [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: '', description: 'URL', name: 'url'],
    ])

node('master') {
    sh "echo userInput is: ${userInput}"
}
```

Comment: I tried to use something similar but didn't work for me: sh '''

      echo "${userInput}"
      '''

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes around ${userInput}?